# ASP.Net Login Control - is there a list of numerical status codes?

Tags: asp.net, list, authentication, integer, status

Is there a list of status codes for the login control? Is there a return value for the login control that an integer?

When a user hits the submit button on a login control, what gets sent? Is the status code returned numerical, or an actual code in words?

And, is there any built-in function(s) to help find the value(s)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not asking for any tools, I'm asking for a list of status codes for the login control. When a user hits the submit button on a login control, what gets sent? Is the status code returned numerical, or an actual code in words?

Comment: Sure, I'll add the note to the question.